# ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Para la importación de cotizaciones desde Yahoo Finances, utilizo el siguiente script.

```
start = "2000-1-1"
#end = date.today()
end = "2019-3-30"

os.chdir("G:/Py_2019/Py_micartera_POO/Ficheros_Yahoo")

"""Nombres de columnas del fichero csv: "lista_nombres" y "lista_tickers" """
data = pd.read_csv("lista_valores_yahoo.csv")

# Let's define a function to do it 
def importar(tickers,start,end):
    def data(ticker):
        return pd_data.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',start,end)    
    datas = map(data,tickers)    
    return pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker','Date'])

todos_los_precios = importar(data["lista_tickers"],start,end)
# Reset the index
precios_ajustados = todos_los_precios[['Adj Close']].reset_index()
# Now we put the cp of stocks in columns
cierre_diario = precios_ajustados.pivot('Date','Ticker','Adj Close')
# Cambiar el nombre de las columnas
cierre_diario = cierre_diario.rename(columns = data["lista_nombres"])
seleccion = cierre_diario['2016-01-01':'2019-03-30']
seleccion[:3]
```

Me devuelve un datafarme correctamente.

Si como fecha "end" utilizo   "end = date.today()", me devuelve el error

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

¿Cuál es la explicación?. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Hola efueyo, te aconsejo colocar la traza completa del error. Sin poder reproducir el ejemplo (estaría bien que añadieras el contenido de `data["lista_tickers"]` al menos, para reproducirlo) lo primero que se me ocurre es que sea `precios_ajustados.pivot` la causante del mismo y se explicaría por tener una fecha repetida para el mismo `ticker`, lo que causa que no sepa cual valor de `Adj Close` tomar  a la hora de pivotar la tabla... Mira a ver si puedes agregar lo mínimo para que se pueda reproducir a ver si podemos dar con lo que está pasando. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias Patricio. He vuelto a ejecutar el script, para colocar la traza completa del error y, sorprendentemente, hoy me funciona correctamente con ambas fechas. Aunque no lo puedo asegurar, lo más probable es que el fallo estuviera en el fichero "lista_valores_yahoo.csv", dado que he continuado trabajando en mi programa y tuve que actualizar algunas cosas en él. Si le parece correcto, dejo esta pregunta unos dias más, hasta asegurarme de que Vd. ha leido mi comentario, y procederé a eliminarla, puesto que dejarla quizás no aporte mucho valor a otros usuario.